# HTML Iframe blank with certain site

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to make an iframe like this, `<iframe src="http://www.fonefinder.net"></iframe>` What comes up is just a blank white space. If I replace the link with another one, it works fine. I honestly don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Chose answeres on your previous questions.

Comment: @Nerd-Herd I don't understand what you are saying...

Comment: @CJSculti you need to accept the answers on your previous question else people are demotivated to answer your questions

Comment: @AnkurMittal I don't see any button to accept answers?

Comment: @AnkurMittal I just accepted all of the answers on my questions that helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

if you check the console you will see an error

`Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.`

The author doesn't want you to frame his/her site, you can read more about it

[Overcoming "Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options)